# Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Input 0 of layer conv2d_21 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, conv-neural-network

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 48, 48, 1) for input Tensor("conv2d_21_input:0", shape=(None, 48, 48, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 48, 48, 3).
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is the relevant code:

```
    from google.colab import drive

#drive.mount('/content/drive')

!ls "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/"

!cp "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/happy vs angry.zip" "happy vs angry.zip"



!ls

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from zipfile import ZipFile

zf = ZipFile('/content/happy vs angry.zip', 'r')
zf.extractall('happy vs angry')
PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname('/content/happy vs angry'), 'happy vs angry')
train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
test_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'test')

train_happy_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'happy')  # directory with our training 
train_angry_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'angry')  # directory with our training 
test_happy_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'happy')  # directory with our validation 
test_angry_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'angry')  # directory with our validation 
batch_size=64
IMG_HEIGHT = 48
IMG_WIDTH = 48

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our training data
test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our validation data

#train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True)
#test_image_generator= ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True)
train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           color_mode="grayscale",
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='binary')

val_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=test_dir,
                                                              color_mode="grayscale",
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='binary')
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(64,3, activation='relu', input_shape=(48,48,1)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Conv2D(32,3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Conv2D(64,3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(2,activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.summary()
import numpy as np
import random
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img

# Let's define a new Model that will take an image as input, and will output
# intermediate representations for all layers in the previous model after
# the first.
successive_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[1:]]
#visualization_model = Model(img_input, successive_outputs)
visualization_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = successive_outputs)
# Let's prepare a random input image from the training set.
happy_img_files = [os.path.join(train_happy_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(train_happy_dir)]
angry_img_files = [os.path.join(train_angry_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(train_angry_dir)]
img_path = random.choice(happy_img_files + angry_img_files)

img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(48, 48))  # this is a PIL image
x = img_to_array(img)  # Numpy array with shape (150, 150, 3)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)  # Numpy array with shape (1, 150, 150, 3)

# Rescale by 1/255
x /= 255

# Let's run our image through our network, thus obtaining all
# intermediate representations for this image.
successive_feature_maps = visualization_model.predict(x)

# These are the names of the layers, so can have them as part of our plot
layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]

# Now let's display our representations
for layer_name, feature_map in zip(layer_names, successive_feature_maps):
  if len(feature_map.shape) == 4:
    # Just do this for the conv / maxpool layers, not the fully-connected layers
    n_features = feature_map.shape[-1]  # number of features in feature map
    # The feature map has shape (1, size, size, n_features)
    size = feature_map.shape[1]
    # We will tile our images in this matrix
    display_grid = np.zeros((size, size * n_features))
    for i in range(n_features):
      # Postprocess the feature to make it visually palatable
      x = feature_map[0, :, :, i]
      x -= x.mean()
      x /= x.std()
      x *= 64
      x += 128
      x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
      # We'll tile each filter into this big horizontal grid
      display_grid[:, i * size : (i + 1) * size] = x
    # Display the grid
    scale = 20. / n_features
    plt.figure(figsize=(scale * n_features, scale))
    plt.title(layer_name)
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(display_grid, aspect='auto', cmap='viridis')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-49-d8344f298369> in <module>()
     23 # Let's run our image through our network, thus obtaining all
     24 # intermediate representations for this image.
---> 25 successive_feature_maps = visualization_model.predict(x)
     26 
     27 # These are the names of the layers, so can have them as part of our plot

10 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1147 predict_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1122 predict_step  **
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:927 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:719 call
        convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:888 _run_internal_graph
```

I keep getting this error and i don't know what is wrong Basically i am training

a model for facial expression and the image datasets is gray scale. The the image is (48,48 ) pixels.-----------------------------------------------------

```
 output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:886 __call__
        self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:216 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_21 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 48, 48, 3]
```

Comment: Are you sure you have only grey scale images in your data set? It seems that there are also coloured images that you input, as the last dimension is 3 in the error. Just check that, I mean make sure you have only grey scale images.

Comment: yes its only gray scale images @CatalinaChircu

Comment: This is the link: https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge/data
 i am only classifying anger and happy emotion just using those folders @CatalinaChircu

Comment: I do not think we can say much without actual code, you are just providing error messages that mean little without context.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro i have added the link , i am sorry for not adding it earlier i am still new to this.

Comment: No, not a link to all your code, you  have to include the relevant code in the question. (not all of your code of course).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Noted thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is right here:

```
img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(48, 48))  # this is a PIL image
```

By default, `load_img` loads images in color (3 channels), so even grayscale images are loaded as color, where each channel has the same value as the grayscale channel. To force `load_image` to produce a one-channel image, you should use the `color_mode` parameter:

```
img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(48, 48), color_mode='grayscale')  # this is a PIL image
```

This will produce a grayscale one-channel image and the prediction should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the this but when i try to fit the model it says
 "ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))"
Same is the case when i try to plot the training images using matplotlib.pyplot ::::: "TypeError: Invalid shape (64, 48, 48, 1) for image data "

Comment: For the labels, you must have the shape of the number of classes you want to classify into. In your case, the number of facial expressions you want to detect. It is certainly not 1 (one).